# JLabel on top of another JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Is it possible to add a JLabel on top of another JLabel? Thanks.

Comment: sorry...why would that make senses??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is yes, as a [`JLabel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) is a [`Container`](http://file:///C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-6-doc/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html), so it can accept a [`Component`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) (a `JLabel` is a subclass of `Component`) to add into the `JLabel` by using the [`add`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) method:

```
JLabel outsideLabel = new JLabel("Hello");
JLabel insideLabel = new JLabel("World");
outsideLabel.add(insideLabel);
```

In the above code, the `insideLabel` is added to the `outsideLabel`.

However, visually, a label with the text "Hello" shows up, so one cannot really see the label that is contained within the label.

So, the question comes down what one really wants to accomplish by adding a label on top of another label.

---

**Edit:**

From the comments:

> well, what i wanted to do was first,
>   read a certain fraction from a file,
>   then display that fraction in a
>   jlabel. what i thought of was to
>   divide the fraction into 3 parts, then
>   use a label for each of the three.
>   then second, i want to be able to drag
>   the fraction, so i thought i could use
>   another jlabel, and place the 3'mini
>   jlabels' over the big jlabel. i don't
>   know if this will work though..:|

It sounds like one should look into how to use layout managers in Java.

A good place to start would be [Using Layout Managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), both from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html).

It sounds like a [`GridLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) could be one option to accomplish the task.

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
p.add(new JLabel("One"));
p.add(new JLabel("Two"));
p.add(new JLabel("Three"));
```

In the above example, the [`JPanel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) is made to use a `GridLayout` as the layout manager, and is told to make a row of `JLabel`s.

Comment: oh. cool thanks! im not really familiar with these so i asked here. :)

Comment: well, what i wanted to do was first, read a certain fraction from a file, then display that fraction in a jlabel. what i thought of was to divide the fraction into 3 parts, then use a label for each of the three. then second, i want to be able to drag the fraction, so i thought i could use another jlabel, and place the 3'mini jlabels' over the big jlabel. i don't know if this will work though..:|

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your original question is yes for the reasons given that any Component can be added to a Container.

The reason you don't see the second label is because by default a JLabel uses a null layout manager and the size of the second label is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. So all you need to do is set the bounds of the second label and away you go.

You can't use a layout manager if you want to drag components around because as soon as you resize the frame etc, the layout manager will be invoked and the components will be repositioned based on the layout manager of the component.

Comment: oh. but is it possible to have a label on top of another, and be able to drag both labels as one? :|

Comment: If the mouse listener is added to the parent label, then all the children will also be dragged when it is moved.

Comment: oh..but a friend said that it's not possible.. said i should use a panel. wah. now im lost. :|

Comment: It is possible and I already told you how to do it. Its 4 lines of code, 2 to create the labels one to set the bounds of the child label and the 4th to add the child label to the parent label. It should take about 5 minutes to test it. Try it and post your SSCCE if it doesn't work. If you don't know what a SSCCE is then search the web.

Answer (score 0):

it's a matter of layout.
you can do that using null layout (with hard coded locations) or with a custom layout.

Comment: I've been trying to do this, but it doesn't work for me. :c maybe i'm doing something wrong. i'll try again. thanks Omry!

Comment: you can use the list() function to get a nice dump of the current container hierarchy, should help you debug your problem.

Comment: great! thanks! should i encounter problems again, can i post it here again?

Comment: if it's about the same question, sure.
if your current question is solved, accept one of the answers and if you have another question just create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `JLayeredPane` and set it's border to No Border.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's an easy way if you use a designer! Like the one in Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

you can add put them above each others by using the horizontal or vertical gap (hgap,vgap) the attributes of the layout
`JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1,-40,0));
//the  40 is the hgap , make it the same with the label height .`