# how do you drag and drop more than 1 value into a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm making a Drag and Drop map maker. I've got the drag and drop working for the terrain, you drag and drop little icons into the squares. I've also tried to have it so that you can drag and drop items onto the terrains, but instead of going over the terrains, they overwrite them. I'm using `JLabels` for this. I'm sorry that I can't provide a source code because I'm on someone elses computer in a different country on holiday.

Comment: The source would help us figure out what you're doing wrong. :(  Regardless -- enjoy your holiday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you use panels instead (of labels) and drag labels into it for each image? So create a label per image.

Comment: Yep, either that or a JLayeredPane. 1+

Answer (score 0):

```
JLabel outsideLabel = new JLabel("Hello");
JLabel insideLabel = new JLabel("World");
outsideLabel.add(insideLabel);
```

thank you coobird (user)
[JLabel on top of another JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513178/jlabel-on-top-of-another-jlabel)